# How to store the stdClass Object data for variable in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actually, I want to store campusId in one variable how to store.

This is my output array data:

```
Array
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 376
            [menuid] => 490
            [campusId] => 465
            [configid] => 838
            [gradeId] => 
            [accountId] => 0
            [createdDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updatedOn] => 2019-12-18 03:23:03
            [isArchived] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Comment: which array you print_r() here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $array['data']->campusId;
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered by u_mulder that is right. If you want to store value in a different value.

```
$yourVar = $array['data']->campusId;

echo $yourVar;
```